# Are there unknown quota limits with Cloud Firestore Blaze plan? Flutter Firestore app falls off a cliff each day

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a flutter/firestore app which falls off an invisible cliff each day.  Everything works fine, then suddenly when I get to around 100k reads for the day it stops working for all users.  I am on the Blaze plan which I understood would not have a daily limit.  There are no errors thrown, it just simply will not work.

Is there another setting inside the console which needs attention to fully utilize the Blaze plan?

Comment: as of [firebase pricing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) only 50k reads/day are free. Do you have a spending limit for the blaze plan?

Comment: but I think the flame plan (which no longer can be bought as of Jan 2020) had 100k reads included

Comment: From the documentation there are no spending limits for the Blaze plan, only budget alerts.  The budget alerts do not prohibit you from exceeding, they only alert you to the overage.